# Systemd service configuration using environment variable

Tags: linux, systemd

How do i set the MemoryLimit using environment variable 
I have tried set MemoryLimit field by using the variable MY_LIMIT like this, 
**The Service configuration:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Blabla

[Service]
Environment="MY_LIMIT=1024"
MemoryLimit=$MY_LIMIT
ExecStart=script.sh
```

But this doesnt seems to work 
As we see that

```
sudo systemctl show myservice
```

Show that the MemoryLimit is a assigned with this value instead

```
MemoryLimit=18446744073709551615
```

Comment: In your service config /etc/systemd/system/yourservice.service. Add Environment="YOURMEMLIMIT"

Comment: Thanks mate,  but that is what i have done

Comment: oh yes, I see that now. :( I am wondering if interpolation is allowed in the service config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> systemd has an Environment directive which sets environment variables for executed processes. [source](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html)

So your `MY_LIMIT` won't get interpreted when set in `MemoryLimit`.

Also `MemoryLimit` is deprecated, use `MemoryMax=` instead. [source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html)

So what you should set is: `MemoryMax=1024M`

Comment: Thanks , MemoryMax is unknown Lvalue on my systemd(229), The example you gace refer to ExecStart  that worj form me as well , but not when using  it in MemoryLimit

Comment: because the environment variables will only only be interpreted for exec*

Comment: It seems that you right, isn't there any option to use variables inside service configuration ?

Comment: No, not they I know of. Unlike sysv init scripts systemd unit files are not scripts. Why do you want to do that anyway? Feels to me like you are trying to make the same setting at two different places.

Comment: I have a generic config file , that i want to use with EnvironmentFile=my.conf

Comment: The edit , you made , is not what i meant. I`m not interested in calling ExecStart with Params. I want to limit memory using external config file , using EnvironmentFile, Thanks